# Apache Commons CSVParser - how to split columns to separate keys?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, parsing

I'm trying to map my CSV file into the POJO class in Spring Boot, but still I get nulls from my parser. This is probably because of the fact that parser put all columns from my CSV files as one key (doesn't split them). That's why instead of finding first column header called "Pos_holder", it returns all the headers in one place, which is not understable for it.

Here's the code of my CSV parser:

```
class CounterpartyResourceCsvParser {

    CounterpartyResource mapToResource(Map<String, String> map, int rowNum, String userId) {
        CounterpartyResource counterpartyResource = new CounterpartyResource();
        counterpartyResource.setPositionHolderId(getOrThrow(map, "Pos_holder", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setPositionHolderIdType(getOrThrow(map,"position_holder_id_type",rowNum,userId));
        counterpartyResource.setPositionHolderEmail(getOrThrow(map, "Email_pos_holder", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setParentEntityId(getOrThrow(map, "Ultimate_parent", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setParentEntityIdType(getOrThrow(map,"ultimate_parent_entity_id_type",rowNum,userId));
        counterpartyResource.setParentEntityEmail(getOrThrow(map, "Email_parent", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setParentInvestmentStatus(getOrThrow(map, "Parent_col_inv_sta", rowNum, userId).toUpperCase());
        counterpartyResource.setFinancialInstitutionFlag(getOrThrow(map, "Fin_inst_flag", rowNum, userId).toUpperCase());
        counterpartyResource.setNdg(getOrThrow(map, "NDG", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setUnderlyingClients(getOrThrow(map, "Underlying_clients", rowNum, userId).toUpperCase());
        counterpartyResource.setResponsiblePerson(getOrThrow(map, "Resp_person", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setResponsibleDeputy(getOrThrow(map, "Resp_deputy", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setResponsiblePersonEmail(getOrThrow(map, "Resp_email", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setResponsibleDeputyEmail(getOrThrow(map, "Deputy_email", rowNum, userId));
        counterpartyResource.setComments(map.get("Comments"));
       
        return counterpartyResource;
    }

    private String getOrThrow(Map<String, String> map, String key, int rowNum, String userId) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).orElseThrow(() -> new FileValidationException(key, userId, rowNum));
    }

    List<CounterpartyResource> csvToResources(InputStream inputStream, String encoding, String userId, boolean isMaksyFieldsAllowed) throws IOException {
        CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader();
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding), format);
        List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();
        
        List<CounterpartyResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(records.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            resources.add(mapToResource(records.get(i).toMap(), i, userId));
        }
        return resources;
    }
}
```

Here's the POJO:

```
public class CounterpartyResource {

    private Long id;
    private String positionHolderId;
    private String positionHolderIdType;
    private String positionHolderEmail;
    private String parentEntityId;
    private String parentEntityIdType;
    private String parentEntityEmail;
    private String parentInvestmentStatus;
    private String financialInstitutionFlag;
    private String ndg;
    private String underlyingClients;
    private String responsiblePerson;
    private String responsibleDeputy;
    private String responsiblePersonEmail;
    private String responsibleDeputyEmail;
    private String entity;
    private String insertionUser;
    private String updateUser;
    private Date insertionTime;
    private Date updateTime;
    private String updatedFieldSummary;
    private Boolean updatedSuccessfully;
    private String comments;
    private String maksyRefClient;
    private String maksyRefNdl;
    private String maksyRefDepo;

    public static CounterpartyResourceBuilder builder() {
        return new CounterpartyResourceBuilder();
    }

    public static class CounterpartyResourceBuilder {
        private Long id;
        private String positionHolderId;
        private String positionHolderIdType;
        private String positionHolderEmail;
        private String parentEntityId;
        private String parentEntityIdType;
        private String parentEntityEmail;
        private String parentInvestmentStatus;
        private String financialInstitutionFlag;
        private String ndg;
        private String underlyingClients;
        private String responsiblePerson;
        private String responsibleDeputy;
        private String responsiblePersonEmail;
        private String responsibleDeputyEmail;
        private String entity;
        private String insertionUser;
        private String updateUser;
        private Date insertionTime;
        private Date updateTime;
        private String updatedFieldSummary;
        private Boolean updatedSuccessfully;
        private String comments;
        private String maksyRefClient;
        private String maksyRefNdl;
        private String maksyRefDepo;

        public CounterpartyResource build() {
            CounterpartyResource counterpartyResource = new CounterpartyResource();
            counterpartyResource.id = this.id;
            counterpartyResource.positionHolderId = this.positionHolderId;
            counterpartyResource.positionHolderIdType = this.positionHolderIdType;
            counterpartyResource.positionHolderEmail = this.positionHolderEmail;
            counterpartyResource.parentEntityId = this.parentEntityId;
            counterpartyResource.parentEntityIdType = this.parentEntityIdType;
            counterpartyResource.parentEntityEmail = this.parentEntityEmail;
            counterpartyResource.parentInvestmentStatus = this.parentInvestmentStatus;
            counterpartyResource.financialInstitutionFlag = this.financialInstitutionFlag;
            counterpartyResource.ndg = this.ndg;
            counterpartyResource.underlyingClients = this.underlyingClients;
            counterpartyResource.responsiblePerson = this.responsiblePerson;
            counterpartyResource.responsibleDeputy = this.responsibleDeputy;
            counterpartyResource.responsiblePersonEmail = this.responsiblePersonEmail;
            counterpartyResource.responsibleDeputyEmail = this.responsibleDeputyEmail;
            counterpartyResource.entity = this.entity;
            counterpartyResource.insertionUser = this.insertionUser;
            counterpartyResource.updateUser = this.updateUser;
            counterpartyResource.insertionTime = this.insertionTime;
            counterpartyResource.updateTime = this.updateTime;
            counterpartyResource.updatedFieldSummary = this.updatedFieldSummary;
            counterpartyResource.updatedSuccessfully = this.updatedSuccessfully;
            counterpartyResource.comments = this.comments;
            counterpartyResource.maksyRefClient = this.maksyRefClient;
            counterpartyResource.maksyRefNdl = this.maksyRefNdl;
            counterpartyResource.maksyRefDepo = this.maksyRefDepo;
            return counterpartyResource;
        }
    // getters & setters
}
```

The nulls which I mentioned before, appear in the following line:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).orElseThrow(() -> new FileValidationException(key, userId, rowNum));
```

My question is: how to make the Apache parser see all the columns' headers separetely? What should I add to my code to split this one long String, so I could achieve pairs like: "Pos_holder"-value; "position_holder_id_type"-value, "Email_pos_holder"-value, etc. ?

EDIT: Here's how my csv sample looks like:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!
Cheers, Mat

Comment: Can you add an example CSV file with the header? Maybe just the first two lines.

Comment: Hi Pavel! I've just added a sample of my CSV to the post. Thanks in advance for your help. Regards, Mat.

Comment: On one note, if you have the flexibility to change dependencies: I really recommend using this project that is specific for converting CSV to POJO: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv

Comment: Thanks Brother. You're right, that one looks really nice. I'll surely consider it for new projects, however in this particular one, I have to stick to my old dependencies.